# Conditional probability: How to find (A'∩Failure)?

Tags: probability, statistics

In a reliability test there is a 42% probability that a computer chip does not survive more than 500 temperature cycles. if a computer does not survive more than 500 temperature cycles,then there is a 73% probability that it was manufactured by company A. What is the probability that a computer chip is not manufactured by company A and does not survive more than 500 temperature cycles?

my solution:

P(Chip survives) = .42

P(A|fails)=.73

by formula of conditional probability, P(A intersection fails) = .42 * (1-.42) = .4234

I need to find P(A' intersection F) I suppose. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine 10000 such chips. "there is a 42% probability that a computer chip does not survive more than 500 temperature cycles" so 4200 do not survive more than 500 temperature cycles and 10000- 4200= 5800 do.

"if a computer does not survive more than 500 temperature cycles,then there is a 73% probability that it was manufactured by company A."  Of the 4200 chips that do not survive more than 500 cycles, .73(4200)= 3066 were manufactured by company A and 4200- 3066= 1134 were not manufactured by company A.

"What is the probability that a computer chip is not manufactured by company A and does not survive more than 500 temperature cycles?"
  Of the original 10000 computer chips, 1134 did not survive 500 temperature cycles and were not manufactured by company A.  The probability is $\frac{1134}{10000}= 0.1134$ or 11.34%.

Comment: Is there any way to do it, with the conditional probability formula instead of taking a number.